# Extract elements from a vector that are repeated n times (R)

Tags: r, vector

I will try to make my point. Imagine I've got a vector with an unknown length and/or content like the next one:

```
col.vector = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5)
```

I want to extract all the elements that are repeated "n" times. Lets say 3 times, then I want to be returned a vector with the respective elements: `c(3, 4)`.

Is there any simple function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `table` if it is based on frequency

```
v1 <- table(col.vector)
as.integer(names(v1)[v1 == 3])
[1] 3 4
```

---

If it is based on repeating elements, use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
v1 <- table(rleid(col.vector))
as.integer(names(v1)[v1 == 3])
```

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
with(rle(col.vector), values[lengths == 3])

[1] 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with `table` -

```
n <- 3
names(Filter(function(x) x == n, table(col.vector)))
#[1] "3" "4"
```